# Button is not enabled when game starts

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying press a button every time I want to start a minigame. In the minigame, it spawns random prefab fruits (up to 10) every second. Here is the code:

```
    public float tiempoRespawn = 1.0f;
    private Vector2 limitesPantalla;
    public Button botonJugar;

    void Start()
    {
        limitesPantalla = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
        botonJugar.onClick.AddListener(ButtonJugarClicked);
    }

    void ButtonJugarClicked()
    {
        StartCoroutine(frutas());
    }

    private void spawn(){
        GameObject f = Instantiate(frutaPrefab[Random.Range(0, frutaPrefab.Length)]) as GameObject;
        f.transform.position = new Vector2(-limitesPantalla.x * -2, Random.Range(-limitesPantalla.y, limitesPantalla.y));
    }

    IEnumerator frutas()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(tiempoRespawn);
            spawn();
        }
    }
```

I dont' know why, when I start the game, the button is disabled and I can't press it. I have tried to write botonJugar.interactable = true, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: if it's actually disabled then you need to use `botonJugar.enabled = true`

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, it's still disabled when I start the program.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code snippet posted and Button's should be intractable by default so you probably have something else going on to debug in the prefab itself.

1. Is the canvas the prefab is attached to set up to have a GraphicsRaycaster Component?
2. It's possible that something is on top of the button that is a raycast target is stealing the clicks?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what are you referring to.